# Android FIDO2 SDK safetynet attestation format is deprecated

Tags: android, webauthn, safetynet

The safetynet attestation api is deprecated, but the FIDO2 SDK(play service) is still return android-safetynet attestation.

{"fmt":"android-safetynet","attStmt":{"ver":"230514037","response"....}}

FIDO2 supports "android-key" attestation, but the chrome and fido2 sdk (play service) always return android-safetynet attestation.

Will the play service update the attestation format to android-key?

Thanks!

The fido2 sdk(play service) supports android-key attestation or we can still use the safetynet attestation.

Comment: I have the same questions and not able to get answers :(

Comment: The safetynet deprecation information for fido2 attestation had been changed. "deprecationInformation":"The app is allowlisted to use the SafetyNet Attestation API until the full turndown: https://g.co/play/safetynet-timeline."